# Spring Autowired service and controller not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, autowired

I read a lot about this kind of problem here, but it seems my code is good but the autowire is not working :

```
Error creating bean with name 'optionController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private service.InteractionBanque controllers.OptionController.interactionBanque; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [service.InteractionBanque] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here is the code of my Controller :

```
package controllers;


package controllers;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import model.Banque;
import model.Client;
import service.InteractionBanque;
import serviceimpl.InteractionBanqueImpl;

@Controller
public class OptionController {

    @Autowired
    private InteractionBanque interactionBanque;


    @RequestMapping(value="/virement",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model, @ModelAttribute Client client) {
        model.addAttribute("virement", new Virement());
        return "virement";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/virement",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(@ModelAttribute Virement virement, Model model) {

        return "options";
    }

}
```

And the Code of my Service :

```
package serviceimpl;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

import dao.BanqueDAO;
import daoimpl.BanqueDaoImpl;
import model.Banque;
import model.Client;
import service.InteractionBanque;
import utils.SendRequest;

@Service
public class InteractionBanqueImpl implements InteractionBanque {
    public static final int END_ID_BANQUE = 5;
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "/account";

    public boolean connecter(Client client) {
        some code
    }

}
```

And The code of the interface :

```
package service;

public interface InteractionBanque {
    boolean connecter(Client client);
}
```

And my Application class define the `@SpringBootApplication` which should be use to wire everything :

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

SO I don't get it, for me this should do the work but the autowired is not working.

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@SpringBootApplication` scans only package (recursively) within a class that uses it. `InteractionBanqueImpl` is in another package.

Create a package 'app' with `Application` class, and then move to it `controllers` and and other packages. Should be fine.

Comment: Thx for the fast reply, but it seems that I can't create a sub package in eclipse, whenever I try to move a package into an other one it just duplicate on the same level... Is there a way to do that ? 
I read that Java doesn't allow sub packages

Comment: Well I don't use eclipse, but you can put package into another. Packages are folders in source code so you can go there with your file explorer and do it manually by creating appropriate folder structure. Just like @predrag-maric suggest in other answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mati said, you have a problem with packages.

Create a root package for your application and move everything under it, so you have it something like this:

```
+ myapp
  Application.java
  + controller
  + service
  + serviceimpl
```

Comment: Doesn't seems possible trough eclipse, I can't move a package into an other one :(

Comment: It can be done in lots of ways, here is one of them: Right click on a class in Navigator -> Refactor -> Move, and type in a destination package name.

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have about putting your `Application` class in a parent package of the rest of your code will work, but an alternative, if you don't want to change your package structure, would be to use the `@ComponentScan` annotation, specifying the packages that contain components you want to autowire, for example:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"serviceimpl", ...}
```

Comment: I'm not able to create sub package, so this is a good solution, Thx man !
However I would prefer to organize my packages in a better way